# Proxy Smart Contracts

Tags: remix, dapps, proxy-contracts, dsproxy, soldity

I am working on a [KYC smart contract](https://github.com/SoftxTech/KYC-Blockchain/blob/main/contracts/KYC.sol) and I want to provide the upgradable feature so I can add more functions or add more fields to the struct in the future.
I have learned about proxies and the way I separate the storage and the code and I saw the transparent proxy, UUPs, and diamond proxy in my case, I think I have to use diamond especially when I have used UUPs the smart contract exceeds the limit of 24KB so I have to divide the smart contract to many contracts using the diamond mechanism.
i saw many resources talking about diamond mechanism implementation but I don't get how to use it with my smart contract and i saw someone who uses [louper](https://louper.dev/) he just deployed the main diamond and then deployed the smart contracts he wished to add to diamond and used louper to write or read from each contract but i don't see where is the benefits from this because i want one smart contract that users connect to it by a dapp and when they call a function they get it from the updated place also the storage keeps saving the data so we always connect to one place to fetch the data from and if i would add another fields i could add to somewhere as extended fields.
also, i saw another way to use diamond but i didn't get it why we did such way, and if i tried to use i can't add my array/mapping of struct that store the data of persons to TestState.

```
bytes32 constant DIAMOND_STORAGE_POSITION = keccak256("diamond.standard.test.storage");
  
  struct TestState {
      address myAddress;
      uint256 myNum;
  }

  function diamondStorage() internal pure returns (TestState storage ds) {
      bytes32 position = DIAMOND_STORAGE_POSITION;
      assembly {
          ds.slot := position
      }
  }
```

the UUPs method i tried to use:

```
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20PermitUpgradeable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
    
    contract KYC is Initializable, ERC20Upgradeable, ERC20PermitUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable, UUPSUpgradeable {
        /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
        constructor() {
            _disableInitializers();
    //some other required functionality
        }
    
        function initialize(address initialOwner) initializer public {
            __ERC20_init("MyToken", "MTK");
            __ERC20Permit_init("MyToken");
            __Ownable_init(initialOwner);
            __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
        }
    
        function _authorizeUpgrade(address newImplementation)
            internal
            onlyOwner
            override
        {}
    // remaining functions
    }
```

Currently, i am working on remix because it is easier and i will move to hardhat later.